# Как поделить на число переменную php?

Tags: php, битрикс

Почти никогда не сталкивался с php, а тут появилась задача вывести вторую цену товара поделённую на 12. 
CMS Bitrix. Сразу скажу, из админки второй тип цен не сделать, т.к. тариф не позволяет.

Вот. Цена товара передаётся в переменную $price. Я создаю новую переменную и пишу вот так

```
$priceInstallment = $price / 12;
```

Но такой код выдаёт ошибку: Unsupported operand types. 
Это что получается, переменная $price не число?

В самом шаблоне цена выводится вот так

```
<?=$price['PRINT_RATIO_PRICE']?>
```

Если убрать ['PRINT_RATIO_PRICE'], то выводится просто Array. Походу переменная содержит массив...

Comment: Видимо, не число. Больше тут нечего сказать

Comment: ну видимо... `var_dump($price);` - и смотрите что там у вас...

Comment: `$priceInstallment = $price['PRINT_RATIO_PRICE'] / 12;`

Comment: @Эдуард, да, пробую так. $priceInstallment = $price['PRINT_RATIO_PRICE'] * 1000 / 12;
А как преобразовать теперь в целое число? Что бы не было знаков после точки.

Comment: `$priceInstallment = intval($price['PRINT_RATIO_PRICE'] * 1000 / 12);`

Comment: var_dump($price) первым делом надо делать. А там уже смотреть что есть.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что цена хранится в виде строки (*пример:* 1000rub).

Поэтому попробуйте предварительно обработать эту строку:

```
$price = "1000rub";
$numOnlyStr = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $price);
echo $numOnlyStr/12;
```

Comment: Добавил информацию в сообщение. Переменная похоже содержит массив...

Comment: Что значит похоже? Делайте var_dump($price) и смотрите в каком ключе массива лежит число.